# high torque and high rpm dc motors

Tags: dc-motor, automotive, speed, torque

I am making an electric 4x4 car, will it make a difference in overall speed if:
Case1: all 4 motors are high torque and relatively low rpm
Case2: 2 high torque relatively low rpm and 2 high rpm relatively low torque

if Case2 will provide better speed, how much? (no numbers, i mean to what extent? (what will it depend on?))
i know high enough torque and high rpm will be faster, but i can't afford it

Comment: 2 seems strange: as soon as you go over the nominal RPM of the slow high-torque motors they're going to stop helping, surely? (1) is better - presumably there are gearboxes as well?

Comment: why? the idea is for the first push to get the car moving the 2-high-torque-motors will operate and the other two will be of little help a more as extra load,
while after the car starts moving no need for high torque anymore, then the other 2-high-rpm-motors will have the ability to give more rpm and thus forcing the other to low-speed motors to just go with it,

this is my idea, no clue if it applies

Comment: the motors are geared, i'm doing no gearing

Comment: To answer the question, "what will it depend on?", have a look at this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43066/how-to-improve-torque-and-rpm-of-a-dc-motor/